# Are there any free Ajax implementation of a HTML editor that can be used in the browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax

What I'm looking for is something similar to [this ASP.net Ajax Control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx).

However, I need a solution that uses only free technologies (e.g. PHP, Javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Comment: WOW has that improved since I last looked at it.

Comment: Yes indeed. Its plug-in architecture and documentation are also much improved and way ahead of FCKEditor (haven't yet looked at CKEditor but the docs were no better).

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked **[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)** (ex **FCKEditor**). This is one of the most powerful editors. But it depends what your end users are. If they're developers then consider something similar that SO uses (**[WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/)**). Much easier and faster to use. SO guys actually changed it to some degree but the original was used at first.

Basically you don't need it to tie to any server-side technology as long as it's programmable on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most popular is the FCKeditor - now renamed [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: +1 - this is what we use and it works quite well.